# Breadth First Search Python code to Depth First Search

Tags: python

I have written some code that conducts a BFS when a graph is defined. I now need to Edit the code to do a DFS, does anyone know what i need to change to complete this?

This is the BFS code i have now:

```
class MyQUEUE: # Just an implementation of a queue.
def __init__(self): # Initialises the queue to an empty queue.
    self.holder = []

def enqueue(self,val):
# Appends item val onto the end of the queue.
    self.holder.append(val)

def dequeue(self):
    # Pops the head off the queue and returns it value.
    val = None
    try:
        val = self.holder[0]
        if len(self.holder) == 1:
            self.holder = []
        else:
            self.holder = self.holder[1:]
    except:
            pass
    return val

def IsEmpty(self):
    # Returns True if the queue is empty.
    result = False
    if len(self.holder) == 0:
        result = True
return result


def BFS(graph,start,end):
# Traverses the graph using a Breadth First Search starting
# from the start node with end being the goal node. Uses a
# queue to store the nodes that are current leaves at the
# fringe of the search.

q = MyQUEUE() # make an empty queue first
q.enqueue([start]) # add the start node onto the queue
while q.IsEmpty() == False:
    path = q.dequeue()
    last_node = path[len(path)-1]
    print (path)
    if last_node == end:
        print ("VALID_PATH : ", path)
    for link_node in graph[last_node]:
        if link_node not in path:
            new_path = []
            new_path = path + [link_node]
            q.enqueue(new_path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert BFS code for a graph into a DFS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788345/convert-bfs-code-for-a-graph-into-a-dfs-code)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of append - insert at the beginning:

modify:

```
self.holder.append(val)
```

to:

```
self.holder.insert(0, val)
```

**Explanation**

While BFS "pills" the neighbors "layer by layer" a DFS goes "all the way to the bottom" and back. By changing the order we iterate the neighbors (recursively) we are, in fact, modifying the BFS into DFS.

**UPDATE**

As Kaya commented below, if we care about performance we should use append/pop instead of insert because insert takes O(n) while append/pop are O(1)

Comment: If you want to use a list as a stack, you should use `append(...)` and `pop()` instead of `insert(0, ...)` and slicing, because the former take O(1) time and the latter take O(n) time.

Comment: @kaya3 you're right, that's definitely a better option, answer updated!